# Prove left solvability in G: for every a and b in G, there is some x in G so that a * x = b.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be a group, with operation *. Prove left solvability in G: for every a and b in G, there is some x in G so that a * x = b.

here is what i am thinking:

let G be group with operation * so * is binary in G since $a$ is in G then $a \cdot x = b$ is in G

Answer (score 1):

Hint: A group $G$ is closed under inverses, multiplication, and the operation is associative. So if $a, b \in G$, then $a^{-1}b \in G$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
Since $G$ is a group, $G$ has an identity element $e$ and $a$ has an inverse $a^{-1}$. See what happens when you set $$x = a^{-1} * b$$

Now use the group axioms (such as associativity) to simplify.

Comment: simplify: a * x = b. so does this means the prove is done.

Comment: @kate There's no $-$ symbol here. There's only the operation $*$.

Comment: is there more to this question that i am not seeing?

Comment: @kate The goal is to simplify $a*x = a*(a^{-1} *b)$. What do you know about groups that can help simplify this?

Comment: this also simplify to a * x = b

Comment: @kate Exactly. So $x = a^{-1} * b$ works in the equation, which was the goal of the problem.